# options creation for plugins

Tags: plugins, options

I am new to wordpress and learning to create plugins.
I want to know how wordpress itself create options in 'wp_options' table for plugin during plugin installation or activation?
How wordpress decide about these option values, which is sometimes serialized data?

Answer (score 0):

There are some functions associated with manipulating the variables found in the `wp_options` table.

[add_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option): Create a new value in the table. Example `add_option('var_name', 'value')` will store  `option_name = 'var_name'` and `option_value =  'value'`. `add_option()` is used only when saving a value for the first time. Has an `autoload` parameter.

[get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option): Retrieve that value. Example: `get_option('var_name')` will return the string `value`.

[update_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option). Will update the value of an option. Can also be used instead of `add_option()`, but it lacks the `autoload` parameter.

As for serializing data, Wordpress will do it automatically if you use the above options with an array.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress includes a [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), that handles all aspects of registering and updating options. I would strongly recommend using the Settings API rather than using `add_option()`/`update_option()` directly.

I've written [a tutorial on implementing the Settings API in Themes](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/); Plugins would be almost identical, except they would use [`add_options_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page) instead of [`add_appearance_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page).

More specific answers would require a more specific question.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your reply. My specific question is, when I created one small plugin 'The Wall' given in book 'WordPress Plugin Development Beginner's Guide' by 'Vladimir Prelovac' and activated it, I found 'wp_wall' option get created in 'wp_options' table. I want to know, how wordpress created this option itself and how it decide about content of 'wp_wall' option?